# How to parse git commit id in android .go

Tags: android, git, go

As title,
I try to call

```
cmd := exec.Command(commit_id, "=", "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)")
cmd.Run()
fmt.Println("commit_id = ", commit_id);
```

But the result is null.
Does somebody know how to parse git commit-id?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    var commitid string
    var sout, serr bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command("git", "rev-parse", "--short", "HEAD")
    cmd.Stdout = &sout
    cmd.Stderr = &serr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(serr.String())
    } else {
        commitid = sout.String()
        fmt.Println("commit_id =", commitid)
    }
}
```

I am new to Golang. The code could be better. I followed the example in [Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) and it seems that it works this way.

Comment: Note that after extracting the commit hash ID, you may want to remove the trailing newline produced by `git rev-parse`.

Comment: @Alan I tried `foo.go` which contains the code in a git repository and use `go run foo.go`. It printed `commit_id = <shorthash>`. How did you try it?

Comment: @Alan I don't have an Android development environment, so I can just test the code in a git repository. In the repository which has already had some commits, I created a file named `foo.go` and pasted the code in my answer in `foo.go`, and then ran `go run foo.go`.

Comment: @ElpieKay, thanks for your help. I try success in my git repository but still failed in android go :(

btw, fmt.Println(serr.String()) didn't print any log

Comment: @ElpieKay, I change "git" to ""/usr/bin/git"" and got success, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Save the below code as `commit_hash.go`

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    commit, err := commitHash()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\x1b[31;1m%s\x1b[0m\n", fmt.Sprintf("error: %s", err))
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("commit_id=%s", commit)
}

func commitHash() (string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("git", "rev-parse", "--short", "HEAD")
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("%w; %s", err, stderr.String())
    }
    return stdout.String(), nil
}
```

then run it from your git repository:

```
go run commit_hash.go
```